# Getting multiple selected value from v-chip-groups

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

there are two arrays

```
categoryArr=['test','demo'] and regionArr = ['GJ','MH']
```

i am using v-chip-groups to display this array values in chips

```
<v-row>
        <v-chip-group
          class="float-right"
          multiple
          v-model="rgSelected"
          active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-2"
        >
          <v-chip filter v-for="(region,i) in regionArr" :value="region" :key="i">{{region}}</v-chip>
        </v-chip-group>
      </v-row>
      <v-divider class="my-2"></v-divider>
      <span style="font-size:1.5rem">Category</span>
      <br />
      <v-row>
        <v-chip-group
          class="float-right"
          multiple
          v-model="ctSelected"
          active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-2"
        >
          <v-chip filter v-for="(category,i) in categoryArr" :value="category" :key="i">{{category}}</v-chip>
        </v-chip-group>
      </v-row>

I'm using watch here
watch: {
    rgSelected: "showDuedate",
    ctSelected: "showDuedate"
  }

methods: {
    showDuedate() {
      console.log(this.ctSelected, this.rgSelected);
    }
  },
```

and the v-model are ctSelected =[] and rgSelected = [].
But when i click on 'GJ' the `rgSelected = ['GJ']` 
and after that if i click on 'test' the output displays `ctSelected=['GJ','test'] and rgSelected=['GJ']`.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it here on mine and there are no errors and all was fine. Seems vuetify version issue, please upgrade it. I solve it after upgrading.

here's the result.

```
ctSelected:  -- rgSelected : GJ
ctSelected: test -- rgSelected : GJ
ctSelected: test,demo -- rgSelected : GJ
```

the v-chips

[image]

Comment: Why did you down voted it ? Nothing wrong with your code cause I tried it and everything was fine. check my updated answer. I present image